# Check that an array is increasing

Tags: ruby

I am just wondering if there is a way to check if the array is increasing ?

Here is my solution, but I am searching for more beautiful way:

```
n = - 1

@arr.flatten.each { |e| 
    return false if e < n
    n = e
}
```

Comment: When you say "check if the array is increasing" do you mean you want to check if the array is sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @tokland That "duplicate" seems rather complicated for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
if @arr.sort.uniq == @arr
  # array is increasing
else 
  # array not increasing
end
```

This will sort the array and drop duplicate values, then compare it to the original array.

If your original array is always increasing, it should match the sorted, de-duplicated array.

**EDIT:**

While this solution gives the desired result, this is not the best solution (see comment below). I would suggest going with toch's solution instead.

Comment: This is O(n log n)-strict while using `each_cons` + `any?` is O(n)-lazy. There is really no reason to do it this way.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
> arr = [1, 4, 5, 6]
> arr.each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| (a <=> b) <= 0 }
 => true
```

You can add it to Array class

```
class Array
  def is_sorted?
    each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| (a <=> b) <= 0 }
  end
end
```

Comment: why not `each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| a <= b }`?

Comment: @tokland Your version works also, but the `<=>` operator is the one to use when you want to sort objects. For instance, [Comparable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html) relies on it.

Comment: yes, there are some objects that implement <=> but do not include comparable (i.e. Array) who knows why. So in the general abstraction I'd use it, but not in the first since the OPs is sorting numbers. Just a detail. +1 anyway, although this exact question was already answered :-)

Comment: @tokland ok, thanks for the info. I should check next time for the duplicate.